# Organize and re-order files by drag and drop angular from array

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I work on feature and the feature need to give the user the ability to re order the file before generate it to the server. I use ng bootstrap for creating the modal and get as inputs array of files then I show the files in the modal. How can the user replace the order of the files on the modal? I need a package that let you re order the file from the UI.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would heartily recommend using ["@angular/cdk"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cdk) package, which is maintained by Angular team itself, meaning it will most probably always be updated with upcoming angular releases, decently tested, well documented and you should get proper support from devs.

I've used it's drag and drop features in multiple projects so far and never had any problems, though as always - your mileage may vary.

The package's API (including drag and drop) is documented on the material components site:
https://material.angular.io/cdk

Basic example of reordering lists using drag and drop:
https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#reordering-lists

Note that while the docs are hosted as part of material docs, you don't need the material dependency itself, only the CDK package.

Comment: Hey, Its work but I don't have a animation when I drag and drop what the problem? @TotallyNewb

Comment: The API adds classes to certain items in certains states, but comes with no pre-defined styles For exmaples on how to add animations see:
https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#styling
and
https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#animations

Or just open the provided examples in stackblitz and look at the css files.

Comment: Thanks @TotallyNewb , How can make the drag and drop work RTL ? I use cdkDropList cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" but its work only from left to right

Comment: I haven't used it in RTL / BiDi solutions and I'm native LTR user, but here's my take:
It seems that indexes in the CdkDragDrop event are indexes of **visual** order and not **logical** order, i.e. they will be reversed for RTL elements.

You can ask about it on the CDK git page - perhaps there is some setting in one of providers to reverse it globally. If not, manually reversing the index should be fairly easy - see example in stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3y7uhf